# Get the object value in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to how to get the value of an object in javacript.

If the source matches the country and the type of paymentin in object then it should get the value of speed and fees. For example 'SGD' with type 'credit' should return the speed and fee.

Expected Output:

```
id: transfer  credit: 1 days 1% 
id: insta credit: 1 days 1.5%
```

---

```
function getValue(source, type, ob) {
    var list;
    ob.forEach((cn) => {
      list = cn.country_from.filter((c) => {
        return c.currency== source;
      });
    })
    return `${type} ${list[0].paymentIn[0].credit.number}`;
  }

//inputs
var result  = getValue(source,type,obj);
var source="SGD";
var type="credit";
var obj = [{
    "id": "transfer",
    "country_from": [{
        "currency": [
            "SGD",
            "USD"
        ],
        "paymentIn": [{
            "type": "credit",
            "speed": {
                "unit": "days",
                "number": "1"
            },
            "fee": {
                "type": "%",
                "number": "1"
            }
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "id": "insta",
    "country_from": [{
        "currency": [
            "SGD",
            "USD"
        ],
        "paymentIn": [{
            "type": "credit",
            "speed": {
                "unit": "days",
                "number": "1"
            },
            "fee": {
                "type": "%",
                "number": "1.5"
            }
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55411689/edit), the `[<>]` the stacksnippet editor. Fix your object and prepare a [mcve]. ALso you need to define the object before using it

Comment: There are still missing brackets in your code. Please FIX your `obj`. When you're asking someone to help with your code, posting compilable code is the bare minimum requirement.

Comment: @adiga apologies to all fixed the code format

Comment: So add a [mcve] - you need to think of the order of the vars too. You cannot have the `var result  = getValue(source,type,obj);` before the parts exist. And you are not building a list, you return each time. You many want filter or reduce instead of forEach

Comment: @Senthil Nope. Brackets are still missing. https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/fnm9tLe4/

Comment: What does it mean `return c.country == source;` ?? Where is the `country`??

Comment: @adiga Check this out! I think I did it! https://jsfiddle.net/9hn2mp7b/

Comment: @adiga thanks but updated the json, apologies all

Comment: Id love to see this destructured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First apply the filter to fetch object which match the `country` and `type` and then you can apply loop over filtered array to get the desired output.

```js
const inputCountry="SGD";
const inputType="credit";
const input =
 [
    {
        "id": "transfer",
        "country_from": [
            {
                "currency": [
                    "SGD",
                    "USD"
                ],
                "paymentIn": [
                    {
                        "type": "credit",
                        "speed": {
                            "unit": "days",
                            "number": "1"
                        },
                        "fee": {
                            "type": "%",
                            "number": "1"
                        }
                    }
                ]       
            }
        ]
    }
];

const filteredArr = input.filter(({country_from}) => {
    return country_from.filter(({currency, paymentIn}) => {
        const ispaymentIn = paymentIn.filter(({type}) => {
            return type.toLowerCase() === inputType.toLowerCase();
        })
        return currency.includes(inputCountry) && ispaymentIn;
    });
});

const output = filteredArr.map(({id, country_from}) => {
    let obj = {id};
    country_from.forEach(({paymentIn}) => {
        paymentIn.forEach(({type, speed, fee}) => {
            obj[type] = speed.number + speed.unit + ' ' + fee.number + fee.type;
        });
    });

    return obj;
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: am getting 'Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined' in the line `const ispaymentIn = paymentIn.filter(({type}) => {`

Comment: @Senthil - Check whether you are extracting `paymentIn` property in the filter function parameter. `country_from.filter(({currency, paymentIn})`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```js
var source="SGD";
var type="credit";
var obj = [{ "id": "transfer", "country_from": [{ "currency": [ "SGD", "USD" ], "paymentIn": [{ "type": "credit", "speed": { "unit": "days", "number": "1" }, "fee": { "type": "%", "number": "1" } }] }] }, { "id": "insta", "country_from": [{ "currency": [ "SGD", "USD" ], "paymentIn": [{ "type": "credit", "speed": { "unit": "days", "number": "1" }, "fee": { "type": "%", "number": "1.5" } }] }] }]

function getValue(source, type, ob) {
    var list = [];
    ob.forEach((cn) => {
      cn.country_from.filter((c) => {
      
        let payment = c.paymentIn;
        payment.forEach(pn => {
         if(pn.type == type) {
          const type = `id:${cn.id} ${pn.type}: ${pn.speed.number} ${pn.speed.unit} ${pn.fee.number}${pn.fee.type}`
          list.push(type);
          }
        });
      });
    });
    return list;
  }

//inputs
var result  = getValue(source,type,obj);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: forEach AND filter AND forEach AND push???